# Обращение к скрипту из префаба

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. Имеется префаб, он создается в процессе работы программе(его сначала нет на сцене). Как будет правильно выполнить скрипт, находящийся на нем? Первое действие я знаю, через команду **GameObject.Find** я найду этот префаб, а дальше как?

Comment: Вы создаете новый префаб или инстанциируете уже существующий? Уточните этот момент, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Когда префаб будет клонирован на нем начнут выполняться  прикрепленные скрипты. Все в порядке выполнения функций юнити. Я имею в виду awake ----> start ------>  и тд

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска метода в префабе, получения или установки значения поля можно выполнить следующее:

```
GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObject").GetComponent<NameOfComponent>().NameOfMethod();
```

Или

```
GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObject").GetComponent<NameOfComponent>().NameOfBoolField == true;
```